# Include Empty Values in SSAS MDX query to use in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssas

I have a cube derived from three dimension tables and a fact table

fact_event (date, location, type)
dim_location, dim_type and dim_time

I want to use reporting services to create a report with the following layout

```
SELECT 
    [Location].Members ON COLUMNS,
    [Type].Members ON ROWS,
    [Time].[Hierarchy].[Month] ON PAGES
  FROM [Events]
  WHERE
    [Measures].[Event Count]
```

Reporting Services obviously likes the query flattened and the measure in the column such as

```
SELECT
    [Measures].[Event Count] ON COLUMNS
    {
      [Location].Members *
      [Type].Members *
      [Time].[Hierarchy].[Month]
    } ON ROWS
  FROM [Events]
```

But when it is performed like this rows and columns that do not contain a value are removed.
So for January I might have "New York", "London", "Sydney" 
but for February I only have "New York", "Sydney"

I would like to have an MDX query that would return a 0 for London for that month.

The same goes for the event type as some event types mightn't occur for a particular month but I would like a row of zeros to appear for that month.

I can get the required data by reverting back to sql but it would be a lot more preferable to use the cube. The SQL query that gets me everything I want is

```
SELECT d.[Month], t.[Type], l.[Location], COALESCE(es.EVENT_COUNT, 0) AS EVENT_COUNT
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Month]
      FROM @Dim_Time 
  ) d
  CROSS JOIN @Dim_Type t
  CROSS JOIN @Dim_Location l
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT [Month], [Type], [Location], 
        COUNT(*) AS EVENT_COUNT
      FROM @Fact_Event
      GROUP BY [Month], [Type], [Location]
  ) es ON (d.[Month] = es.[Month] AND t.[Type] = es.[Type] AND 
           l.[Location] = es.[Location])
```

I've included a script to populate some temp tables with appropriate data to demonstrate the above query

```
declare @Dim_Time table ([Month] datetime)
declare @Dim_Location table ([Location] varchar(10))
declare @Dim_Type table ([Type] varchar(10))
declare @Fact_Event table ([Month] datetime, [Location] varchar(10), [Type] varchar(10))

insert into @Dim_Time values ('1 Jan 2011')
insert into @Dim_Time values ('1 Feb 2011')
insert into @Dim_Location values ('New York')
insert into @Dim_Location values ('Sydney')
insert into @Dim_Location values ('London')
insert into @Dim_Type values ('Good')
insert into @Dim_Type values ('Bad')

insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Jan 2011', 'New York', 'Good')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Jan 2011', 'New York', 'Good')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Jan 2011', 'New York', 'Bad')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Jan 2011', 'Sydney', 'Good')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Jan 2011', 'Sydney', 'Good')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Jan 2011', 'Sydney', 'Good')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Jan 2011', 'Sydney', 'Bad')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Jan 2011', 'London', 'Good')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Jan 2011', 'London', 'Bad')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Jan 2011', 'London', 'Bad')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Feb 2011', 'New York', 'Bad')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Feb 2011', 'New York', 'Bad')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Feb 2011', 'Sydney', 'Good')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Feb 2011', 'Sydney', 'Good')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Feb 2011', 'Sydney', 'Good')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Feb 2011', 'Sydney', 'Bad')
insert into @Fact_Event values ('1 Feb 2011', 'Sydney', 'Good')
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Toggle non-empty" button in the SSRS query designer.

http://64.4.11.252/en-us/library/ms403829(SQL.110).aspx

Looks like a dataset with a green funnel underneath it.

> Toggle between showing and not showing
>   empty cells in the Data pane. (This is
>   the equivalent to using the NON EMPTY
>   clause in MDX).

Comment: Thanks Meff. Your answer is the solution to the question I asked. As is common, in order to simplify the question I got rid of the source of the problem I was having. Why it worked in your situation and not mine led me to the solution. A key part of what the question should have been that I'm slicing by attributes of a fact dimension. Once I promoted them to full blown dimensions it worked as you described